# Is there exponential function in scala

Tags: scala

how to write this maths function in scala ? cant find exp in scala.

1/(1+exp(3.4761-101.09*0.05-0.0440))

Comment: The API documentation for this function is the first result if you search Google for "scala exp".

Comment: Seems unecessarily harsh: ScalaDoc 2.12.4 search for exp shows only "scala.language.experimental"

Answer (score 8):

You can find these things yourself, even if you don't think to look in the `scala.math` package object (by clicking on the header in the ScalaDoc).

There's a listing of things by letter at the top left of the Scaladoc page (ever wonder what those things were under the search box?):

[image: By-letter listings]

If you're looking for `exp`, you'd click on `e`, then scroll down through the list that appears on the right until you find it.

[image]

It helpfully tells you that it's there, and that it's in package `math` (which you can click on also, if you need to find where that is).

Comment: import scala.math._  (worked), sorry would had looked all the functions first

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you need to `import scala.math._` or `scala.math.exp`.

```
import scala.math._

scala> exp(1)
res4: Double = 2.718281828459045
```